# R implementation of some new Principal Component Pursuit methods

Tags: r, pca, high-dimensional

I'm looking for R packages implementing some new PCA methods.

The first one is the Stable Principal Component Pursuit method 
of [Zhou *et al.* (2010)](http://statweb.stanford.edu/~candes/papers/StableRPCA.pdf).

The second one is the PCA via Outlier Pursuit algorithm 
of [Xu *et al.* (2012)](http://guppy.mpe.nus.edu.sg/~mpexuh/papers/OutlierPursuit-TIT.pdf).

Both are highly cited papers in statistics, yet I could not find either of them  on the robust or multivariate R task view and was wondering whether somebody more knowledgeable could point me in the 
right direction.

1. Zihan Zhou, Xiaodong Li, John Wright, Emmanuel Candes and Yi Ma
   (2010). Stable Principal Component Pursuit.
2. H. Xu, C. Caramanis, S. Sanghavi (2012). "Robust PCA via Outlier Pursuit", IEEE Transactions on Information Theory, 58(5), pp 3047-3064, 2012.

Comment: I don't understand the recommendations to migrate the question to SO. This  question is clearly more likely to be answered by a statistician than a computer programmer!

Comment: Probably due to the controversy illustrated here: "[Why was this question migrated to SO?](http://meta.stats.stackexchange.com/q/2007/32036)" (I voted to leave it here, FWIW.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try either of these 2 R packages:
[rPCA](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rpca/index.html)
[SURUS](https://github.com/mmolaro/Surus)